# How to get the root of a PrimeFaces tree node?

Tags: primefaces, tree

I have a html page that gets a TreeNode from a controller.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
<ui:composition>
    <pa:panelTree styleClass="corps-grade-list"
        treeContent="#{affectationController.getDossierEnBrefAffectations()}"
        rendered="#{agentModele.estMigre}" />
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

Such that, the `affectationController.getDossierEnBrefAffectations()` is a function that returns this tree node. I would like to get the root node of this tree.

I tried with `treeContent="${affectationControleur.consulterDossierEnBrefAffectations.children[0]}"` because the TreeNode class has the function [getChildren](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=org.primefaces.model.TreeNode&method=getChildren). However it is not the right syntax for EL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you haven't extended the `DefaultTreeNode` class or implemented the interface, do so. Now you can simply add this method to your tree node implementation:

```
public TreeNode getRoot() {
  if (getParent() == null) {
    return this;
  }
  TreeNode root = getParent();
  while (root.getParent() != null) {
    root = root.getParent();
  }
  return root;
}
```

This allows you to use: `#{bean.treeNode.root}`.

If you cannot change the model, you could add something similar in your bean:

```
public TreeNode getRoot(TreeNode node) {
  if (node.getParent() == null) {
    return node;
  }
  TreeNode root = node.getParent();
  while (root.getParent() != null) {
    root = root.getParent();
  }
  return root;
}
```

This allows you to use: `#{bean.getRoot(treeNode)}`.